# Twilio Authy and persistent tokens

Tags: jwt, twilio, token, one-time-password, authy

I'm considering using Twilio's Authy as a one time password authentication solution for my app. I've combed through their [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/api) and I understand how to register a new user with a phone number, and then how to verify that they indeed own that phone.

My question is, once a user has been authenticated, how am I supposed to keep them authenticated in my app? Does Twilio handle any sort of JWT or token generation? Or is Twilio only there to assert that a particular user owns a particular phone number, and it's on me (the developer, or another service like Firebase) to spin up a token associated with that user to use for all future requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You're right that Authy is able to verify that the user is the user that you registered with Authy. It does not do anything to keep a user authenticated in your application though, it's really there to give you a yes or no answer as to whether you trust the user has the device they initially registered with.

As you surmise, it is either up to you or another service to provide a token that you can continue to authenticate requests with. This blog post is a little old (as it uses plain Twilio SMS rather than Authy) but gives you an idea where you could start [building that authentication for passwordless login](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/01/mobile-passwordless-sms-authentication-part-1-building-the-api-with-laravel-and-twilio.html) in an application (in this case in PHP).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I suppose my follow up question is, if it's on me to arrange the rest of the auth flow, what benefit does Authy provide over simple programmable SMS? As far as I can tell, the only advantages are a) Twilio stores and compares the 4-digit code instead of me and b) Twilio has it's own database of phone numbers each unique to a user, and users with unique emails. But I'd probably want to store that info myself anyway, along with the AuthyId to associate my record with Twilio's.

Comment: With the Authy API, if the user uses the Authy app they don't need to use SMS for auth (which can work in areas without phone signal). The Authy app is also more secure than SMS as a transport for codes like that. Authy also does extra work to guarantee SMS delivery as authentication codes are more high priority than, say, a marketing message. If a user loses their device and needs to get access to their Authy account, we have a support team so you don't have to worry about that. There's a few more reasons, but I've run out of space in this comme